# Is every $p$-group the $\mathbb{F}_p$-points of a unipotent group

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gr.group-theory, finite-groups, algebraic-groups, nilpotent-groups

Let $\Gamma$ be a finite group of order $p^n$. Is there necessarily a unipotent algebraic group $G$ of dimension $n$, defined over $\mathbb{F}_p$, with $\Gamma \cong G(\mathbb{F}_p)$?

I have no real motivation for this question, it just came up in conversation and no one knew the answer. There does not appear to be any sort of uniqueness to $G$; both the groups $\mathbb{Z}/p^2 \mathbb{Z}$ and $(\mathbb{Z}/p \mathbb{Z})^2$ have infinitely many lifts to unipotent groups.

---

I am bumping this question to the top because I now suspect I have a counterexample, namely the dihedral group of order $16$, also known as $C_2 \ltimes C_8$, where $C_n$ is cyclic of order $n$. The "obvious" lift of $C_8$ is the additive group of the $3$-truncated Witt vectors, $\mathcal{W}_3$. So the obvious thing to try is a semidirect product $\mathbb{G}_a \ltimes \mathcal{W}_3$. But $\mathbb{G}_a$ has exponent $2$, so an action of $\mathbb{G}_a$ on $\mathcal{W}_3$ must live in the $2$-torsion elements of $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathcal{W}_3)$. I compute that the space of $2$-torsion elements in $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathcal{W}_3)$ has two connnected components, one of which maps $1$ to things that are $1 \bmod 4$ and one of which maps $1$ to things which are $-1 \bmod 4$. Since $\mathbb{G}_a$ is connected, it must land in one component, but the two elements of $C_2$ live in different components.

I've made some partial progress thinking about the structure of connected unipotent groups whose $\mathbb{F}_2$ points are $C_2 \ltimes C_8$, but I've gotten stuck, so I am putting up a bounty for progress either on this case or the questions as a whole.

Comment: If $U$ is smooth connected unipotent of dimension $n$ over $k=\mathbf{F}_p$ then $\#U(k)=p^n$ (use composition series with successive quotients $\mathbf{G}_a$).  Thus, if $\Gamma=G(k)$ for a unipotent $k$-group $G$ of dimension $n$ then by passing to $G_{\rm{red}}$ so that $G$ is smooth we see that if $G$ is not connected then $G^0(k)$ of size $p^n$ must exhaust $G(k)$. In other words, we lose nothing by assuming $G$ is smooth and connected. So it is the same as asking for smooth connected unipotent $k$-groups $U$ if there is any constraint on $U(k)$ beyond its order being $p^n$. Good puzzler.

Comment: This was asked a while ago, as well, but there was no answer. http://mathoverflow.net/questions/69397/p-groups-as-rational-points-of-unipotent-groups

Comment: A step towards an inductive proof:  if $G$ is a unipotent $k$-group, and $c \in Z^2(G(k), Z / p Z)$ is a 2-cocycle (for trivial action), does there exist a polynomial 2-cocycle $\gamma \in Z^2(G, G_a)$ such that $\gamma$ gives $c$ upon taking $k$-points?  I want to attack this one inductively with inflation-restriction with respect to $G$ and $[G,G]$.  But no time for more than a sketchy comment.

Comment: Here is how I would try to prove this.  There exists a faithful homomorphism, $\rho:\Gamma\to \textbf{SL}_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$.  This follows, for instance, from the solution of the Abhyankar conjecture by Raynaud and Harbater.  By counting $\mathbb{F}_p$-points of the flag variety of $\textbf{SL}_n$, there exists a Borel subgroup $B$ that contains the image of $\rho$.  Thus, there exists a faithful homomorphism from $\Gamma$ to a unipotent group.  Replace that unipotent group by the centralizer $U$ of $Z(\Gamma)$.  Thus $Z(U)(\mathbb{F}_p)$ is an additive group that contains $Z(\Gamma)$ . . .

Comment: . . . So there is a unique minimal, connected subgroup $A\subset Z(U)$ such that $A(\mathbb{F}_p)$ equals $Z(\Gamma)$.  Now replace $U$ by $U/A$, and use induction on the rank.

Comment: @JasonStarr: In view of your inductive suggestion it seems that what you call "$n$" (from SL$_n$) is not "$n$" as in the statement of the question, just some unknown integer, in which case such $\rho$ is provided by the regular representation of $\Gamma$ on itself over $\mathbf{F}_p$ (that gives $\rho$ into ${\rm{GL}}_N(\mathbf{F}_p)$, necessarily landing inside SL$_N({\mathbf{F}}_p)$ and even conjugating into $U_N(\mathbf{F}_p)$ since the latter is a $p$-Sylow subgroup).

Comment: @nfdc23.  You are correct.  I realize now the problem with the approach I suggest: why should the centralizer of $Z(\Gamma)$ in $U$, much less the center of the centralizer, be a connected group?

Comment: @JasonStarr: I was wondering about that connectedness issue too but thought I might be overlooking something.

Comment: @JasonStarr It seems like you are saying that, given an connected abelian group $H$ (in your setting, $Z(U)$), and a discrete subgroup $B$, there is a smallest connected group $A$ containing $B$. But that isn't true: consider $H = \mathbb{G}_a^2$ and $B = \{ (x,0) : x \in \mathbb{F}_p \}$. Then $B$ is contained in $\mathbb{G}_a$ embedded in $H$ by either $t \mapsto (t,0)$ or $t \mapsto (t,t^p-t)$. What am I missing?

Comment: @DavidSpeyer. I should *not* have called this the unique smallest subgroup.  I am saying that for a vector space $V$ and a finite subgroup $Z$ of the group of $\mathbb{F}_p$-points of the scheme $\text{Spec}\ \text{Sym}_{\mathbb{F}_p}(V)$, the kernel of the restriction map $V\to \prod_{z\in X} \kappa(z)$ is an $\mathbb{F}_p$-linear subspace of $V$ generating an ideal whose associated closed subscheme is a closed subgroup scheme whose associated group of $\mathbb{F}_p$-points equal to $Z$.

Comment: I think there is a fatal flaw in @JasonStarr's approach. It seems that Jason's method would show that, if $U$ is a unipotent group, and $\Gamma$ is a subgroup of $U(\mathbb{F}_p)$, then there is a unipotent subgroup $G$ of $U$ with $G(\mathbb{F}_p) = \Gamma$. This isn't true. Let $U$ be the group structure on $\mathbb{A}^3$ given by $(x_1,y_1,z_1) \ast (x_2,y_2,z_2) = (x_1+x_2, y_1+y_2, z_1+z_2+x_1^p y_1^p - x_1 y_1)$ and let $\Gamma = \{ (x,y,0) : x,y \in \mathbb{F}_p \} \subset U(\mathbb{F}_p)$.  Then $\Gamma$ is not $G(\mathbb{F}_p)$ for any $2$-dimensional subgroup of $U$. (continued)

Comment: Suppose there were such a $G$, and let $Z$ be the center $\{ (0,0,z) \}$ of $U$. Case 1: $G \supset Z$. Then $G(\mathbb{F}_p) \supset \{ (0,0,z) : z \in \mathbb{F}_p \}$, which is not in $\Gamma$. Case 2: $G \cap Z$ is finite. In that case, the projection $G \to U/Z$ is surjective. But any subvariety of $U$ which surjects onto $U/Z$ generates $U$, contradicting that $G$ is two dimensional.

Comment: I am specifically suggesting to use the faithful representations of $p$-groups arising from Abhyankar's conjecture.  If we realize $\Gamma$ as the Galois group of a finite etale extension $\mathbb{F}_q[t] \subset R$, then for every subgroup $\Lambda \subset \Gamma$, then $R$ is a finite etale extension of the $\Lambda$-invariant subring $S$, with Galois group $\Lambda$.  This is a "complete reducibility" result that is missing for arbitrary representations.  I suggest we projectively complete these rings at $\infty$, and quotient by the maximal ideal of $\infty$ in $\mathbb{F}_q[t^{-1}]$.

Comment: Okay, I'll take a look at Abhyankar's conjecture and see what that does for me. In the mean time, I'll record that the formula was meant to be $(x_1, y_1, z_1) \ast (x_2, y_2, z_2) = (x_1+x_2, y_1+y_2, z_1+z_2 +(x_1 y_2)^p-x_1 y_2)$, sorry for the incorrect subscripts in the previous one.

Comment: Given that this is a duplicate of a question six years earlier, how is this not closed?

Comment: @DrorSpeiser I decided to put the bounty on my own version, rather than the duplicate because I'd rather edit my own question and because it has a bunch of useful comments. If I had (two years ago) seen Gjergji's link to the duplicate before a bunch of those comments showed up, I probably would have self-closed, but it doesn't seem like a big deal either way. Of course, if someone posts a good answer, I'll link it on that question as well to make sure searchers find it.

Comment: Take $a=1+E_{12}+E_{34}+E_{56}$, $b=1+E_{23}+E_{45}+E_{67}\in Mat_{7\times7}(\mathbb{F}_2)$, where $E_{ij}$ has a unique nonzero element at row $i$ and column $j$ equal to 1. Set $c=ab$. Let $V$ be $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_2^7$, and let $D_{16}\cong<x, y|x^2=y^8=xyxy=1>$ act on $V$ by sending $x$ to $a$ and $y$ to $c$. With this action $V$ is an indecomposable module for $D_{16}$. Let $\overline{D_{16}}$ be the Zariski closure of $<a, c>$ in $GL(V)$, which is unipotent. Does it satisfy $\overline{D_{16}}(\mathbb{F}_2)=<a,c>\cong D_{16}$?

Comment: @DrorSpeiser the Zariski closure of a finite set is itself (so not unipotent). I don't see any reason why we should expect any given embedding of D_8 in a unipotent group to come from the F_2-points of a connected subgroup.

Comment: Do you require $G$ to be connected?